# Laravel Registration error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, homestead

I am following the laravel 5.2 documentation on registration and am having some trouble. When I try to register I get the following error after I click the registration button.

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219: in
>   RouteCollection.php line 219

Here is the code for where I want a user to be redirected to after they register, this is in the AuthController.php.

```
protected $redirectTo = "pages.test";
```

Pages is a folder I created in the views folder. The "`pages.test`" file works if I try to access it by typing in http://mywebapp.app/test into the browser. 
Here is the code in my routes controller.

```
Route::get("test", function()
{
  return view("pages.test");
});
```

I have tried setting `$redirectTo = "test"` and "`pages.test.blade.php`" and "`test.blade.php`", none of these work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far i understand your question, you are trying to register users from a html form . If the method in the form is `post` i.e.

```
<form method="post" action="your_action_url" />
```

then route should be

```
Route::post('test',function(){
return view('your_view');
});
```

And if method is `get` then Route should be

```
 Route::get('test',function(){
    return view('your_view');
    });
```

If you want to explore more then see the laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing)

Comment: Thanks I got it working now, I forgot to change the form action to the right url.

Answer (score 2):

when you click submit button you may send post, so you can change it to:

```
Route::post("test", function()
{
  return view("pages.test");
});
```

if you want any, you can use:

```
Route::any("test", function()
{
  return view("pages.test");
});
```

Comment: I tried changing the route to both post and any but I still get the following error. MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:
in RouteCollection.php line 219

Comment: can you provide your form tag

Comment: Yea the problem was the form tag. I forgot to set the action equal to the url I wanted. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
Route::any("test", function(){
    return view("pages.test");
});
```